# In OpenGL, how to clear drawn primitives in a 3D region

Tags: opengl, glut

Let us say, I draw 3 points with glVertex3f at (0,0,0), (9,0,0) and (10,0,0)
I would like to clear all Vertex3f points in the bounding box region (2,-1,-1) to (15, 1, 1) which should include the last two points.

How does one do this in OpenGL?

Comment: OpenGL is blissfully ignorant of all past drawing; it just maintains an array of pixels (called a framebuffer) that get sent to the monitor.  You can limit drawing using the `GL_SCISSOR` or `GL_STENCIL` tests, but this won't affect anything drawn previously.  Generally you have to clear everything and start over any time your scene changes.

Answer (score 2):

Manage your point drawing outside of OpenGL. IE Don't use OpenGL to accomplish this. OpenGL is used for drawing data, not keeping track of it. If you want to get rid of certain objects, don't tell OpenGL to draw them. There are various space-partitioning data structures at your disposal for efficiently finding intersections.

- The naive way is to check to see that all the points in your scene are outside that region before you draw them.
- A better way is to use a *kd*-tree or an octree to exponentially narrow down the number of comparisons you must do.